# Проблема с циклом For в Visual Basic при инкременте 0.1

Tags: циклы, for, visual-basic

Коллеги, добрый день.
Столкнулся со странной проблемой цикла For при написании макроса в Visual Basic.

Для примера, имею я вот такой код:

```
Sub Test_for()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim counter As Integer
    Set cell = Range("A1")

'Первый цикл For
    counter = 0
    For i = 0 To 1 Step 0.1
        cell.Offset(counter, 0).Value = i
        counter = counter + 1
    Next i

'Второй цикл For
    counter = 0
    For j = 0 To 2 Step 0.1
        cell.Offset(counter, 1).Value = j
        counter = counter + 1
    Next j
'Третий цикл For
    counter = 0
    For k = 0.1 To 2.1 Step 0.1
        cell.Offset(counter, 1).Value = k
        counter = counter + 1
    Next k
End Sub
```

Так вот для первого цикла имею вывод вида от 0 до 1 (все верно),
НО! для второго цикла имею вывод от 0 до 1,9 (но должно быть до 2).
Для третьего цикла вывод от 0.1 до 2 (но должно быть до 2.1)!

Коллеги, кто разбирается в нюансах VB, подскажите, что я делаю не так, какие мануалы покурить. Для меня такое поведение циклов непонятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Числа с плавающей точкой имеют ограниченную точность. На последней итерации у вас переменная цикла принимает значение не ровно 2.0, а, например, 2.000000000001 и уже не попадает в верхнюю границу цикла, заданную как 2.

Правильнее всего тут спользовать тип `decimal`, который представляет дробные числа точно в десятичной системе, для этого использовать постфикс `D` у чисел:

```
For j = 0D To 2D Step 0.1D
    cell.Offset(counter, 1).Value = j
    counter = counter + 1
Next j
```

Но можно сделать и более кустарно, если тип `decimal` по каким-то причинам не доступен:

- Не использовать числа с плавающей точкой, делать цикл в целых числах от 0 до 20 и внутри цикла получать нужное значение переменной, деля переменную цикла на 10
- Задать верхнюю границу цикла с небольшим запасом - например, не 2, а 2.05, чтобы это было число заведомо больше 2, но меньше значения для следующей итерации, т.е. чем 2.1

Comment: @CrazyElf , спасибо, что ткнули носом программу первого курса института, ато забывать уже начал) Все таки цикл вида for (int i=0; i < var; ...)  с условием в виде неравенства понадежней будет, имхо) Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @Akina Я про переменную цикла, а вы, наверное, про верхнюю границу цикла. Может быть и там и там проблема в принципе, но это уже детали.

Comment: @Zigzag_Makryak В моё время такому в институте не учили, всё грабли пришлось самому собирать ))  Так то тут регулярно подобные вопросы и про Python и про C# вылезают, так что тема на слуху )